# I want to convert SAML 2.0 requests into WS-FED standard protocol req and vice versa. Does it possible?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, ws-federation

Am having one SP which support WS-Fed standard protocol and IDP which supports SAML2.0 protocol. SO how to use these SP and IDP. any suggestions .. thanx in advance

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Eugenio.

Unless you have a very specific use case, rather use something like ADFS or IdentityServer or Auth0 that supports both protocols and use that as a bridge i.e. let the product do the work.

So the path is: SP --> WS-Fed --> Product --> SAML --> IDP.

Just to re-iterate: doing this yourself is non-trivial.

Comment: thank you nzpcmad ... That means if we keep ADFS in middle of SP and IDP we can use this scenario.Does ADFS is capability of converting ws-fed req to SAML req ?

Comment: Yes - it will bridge the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a protocol translation service. It is possible, but it is a lot of work to make it right (secure, scalable, flexible, etc), and you will have a steep learning curve to master all the details of both protocols.

So (unless you have a lot if time to spare on this, and you really want to dive deep into the subject), I'd suggest getting one off the shelf. There are a few options out there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eugenio Pace